# How to /fill with Armor Stands In 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a lag machine schematic in 1.12.2, and instead of placing 10000 Armor Stands by hand, I was wondering if there was any way to /fill them or use something with World Edit to do the same thing. I looked all over google but could not find anything that worked. I found a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LySru5q3j1U) however it did not work for me nor did it have any error messages, any help is appreciated.

`/fill 351 8 223 192 8 64 torch`(regular command block)

`/execute @e[type=item.item.torch] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand`(chain command block)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your chain command block to Always Active.
Chain command blocks don't run if they aren't active.